# WPF XAML custom attribute on local data template

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

New to WPF. I'd like to pass a parameter to a view.  I think I can use an attribute of the control:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListTemplate">
    <local:ListView TestValue="foo" />
</DataTemplate>
```

...with a `Binding`, eventually, but I don't know how to add `TestValue` in a way that it's recognized by the code behind.

How can I solve this, or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement a dependency property in your `ListView` class:

```
public class ListView : UserControl
{
    public ListView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string TestValue
    {
        get { return (string)this.GetValue(TestValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TestValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TestValueProperty 
        = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(TestValue), typeof(string), typeof(ListView));
}
```

**How to: Implement a Dependency Property:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-implement-a-dependency-property

You can then bind this property to a property of your `DataContext`, i.e. the object to which your `DataTemplate` is applied:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListTemplate">
    <local:ListView TestValue="{Binding SomeSourceProperty}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Ahh, `DependencyProperty` was the missing ingredient. Cheers, trying it out now.